# Matlab matrix sort

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I 've a specific problem of sorting rows in matlab.
This is mine example entry matrix:

```
 A =

 [0 1 1;
  0 1 2;
  1 0 3;
  1 0 4;
  1 1 5;
  0 1 6;]
```

and this is "sorting vector"

```
 V=

  1 
  4 
  6 
  2 
  3 
  5
```

How to get an output matrix like this:

```
B=

 [0 1 1;
  1 0 4;
  0 1 6;
  0 1 2;
  1 0 3;
  1 1 5]
```

?

First I've added vector V to matrix A (last column) but the next step I don't know how it should look. I'm stuck.

In advance, thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rearrange or select any desired rows:

```
B = A(V,:);
```

The same concept could be used for columns and for rearranging, selecting or repeating any desired row or column:

```
V2 = [3 1 3];
B2 = A(:,V2);

B2 = 

 1     0     1
 2     0     2
 3     1     3
 4     1     4
 5     1     5
 6     0     6
```

Learn about colon operator(:) here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html

Answer (score 3):

This might be the answer:

`B = A(V(:),:);`